# Windows phone 8.1 (WinRT) and Windows phone 10 (UWP) app suspending procedure

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a windows 8.1/windows phone 8.1 (WinRT) app published in the windows store. The app uses the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Suspending` event handler to save important app state and statistics into a set of files (not using the built-in settings API for a reason). In order to be "a good boy" I try to comply with the `Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingOperation.Deadline` and call the `Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral()` to be as explicit as possible.

Here are the questions:

1. Do I get it right that I have to call the `Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingDeferral.Complete()` method before the moment of deadline?
2. Are there any noticeable penalties if I do not manage to call it before the deadline? Does it make my app "unresponsive" from the point of view of some system watchful eye?
3. What happens with the threads that are still running in the moment the `Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingDeferral.Complete()` is called? Do they get frozen or something?
4. Is there any difference in behavior between "async" threads i.e. implicit TPL threads or `ThreadPool.RunAsync` and UI thread in the process of app suspending?
5. Am I obligated to explicitly cancel all the async Tasks i.e. `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` instances I own before I call the `Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingDeferral.Complete()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very good article about RT app life cycle: [What You Need To Know About Suspend and Resume in WinRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/06/17/what-you-need-to-know-about-suspend-and-resume-in-winrt/).

If you don’t call `Complete` method before the `SuspendingOperation.Deadline` expires, a timeout occurs and Windows guesses that something bad happened to your app… and, instead of being suspended, it will be terminated.

So, you should finish your job and call Complete before Dedline.

Comment: Thanks for the nice article. It says my app is going to be terminated if I get the Deferral and do not call the Complete method before the deadline but it says nothing about finishing my tasks before deadline. It says my existing threads are just going to be frozen on suspend, no termination. What did you mean saying "If you don't finish the job before deadline - your app will be terminated"?

Comment: Threads will be frozen on suspending if you'll fit in the deadline.

Comment: Again, what do you mean saying "...finish the job before deadline - your app will be terminated."?

Comment: `The SuspendingEventArgs SuspensionOperation object received by this handler provides the time in the future after which Windows will terminate your app, regardless of whether you have finished saving your state! This Deadline property is readonly: it is just a hint for you.`

Comment: `If you don’t call Complete method before the SuspendingOperation.Deadline expires, a timeout occurs and Windows guesses that something bad happened to your app… and, instead of being suspended, it will be terminated.`

Comment: I got that if I do not call the Complete than the app is going to be terminated. So I see that the only condition I have to meet is calling Complete in time. What your words "or finish the job before deadline" mean? Is it some additional condition?

Comment: Just call Complete in time - that's all.